# Any suggestions for multiple out.setText();

Tags: java, swing, windowbuilder

In my Java project with WindowBuilder Pro. I use methods to return a values then `out.setText(value_1);` but when I try to `out.setText(value_2);` a `value_1` has been removed.

My solution is to `String show = out.setText(value_1).concat(value_2)` and then `out.setText(show);`. Does anyone have another suggestions/solutions of this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using a [`JTextArea`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) instead of a `JTextField`. A text area is a multi-line text field and has an `append(String text)` method.

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty simple. Try this :

```
out.setText(out.getText()+value_2);
```

That's it.